# How to say "drawn into the depth"

Tags: idioms

Apologies in advance for the naivety of my question, I am a non-native speaker.

I am trying to say this : "I thought it would be a quick read, but I became fascinated by it and was **drawn into the depth of the subject**".

Is this a correct way to phrase it (in bold)? Or is another way more idiomatic in English?

Comment: Sounds OK to me. Another verb or modifier which is often used in this context  is _absorb/absorbing._

Comment: If I were *deeply drawn* into the subject, not drawn into the *deep subject*, I'd say **drawn deeply into the subject**.

Comment: "into the depths" (plural) might be ever-so-slightly more normal.

Comment: ok, thanks both.